why incorrect convertion of long long to int causes the compiler to error: cannot bind non-const lvalue to an rvalue
My code is given below.
I understand I can't convert long long to int&, but why does the error say "cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘int&’ to an rvalue of type ‘int’"?
Is it possible that in some cases, the compiler will treat a type-mismatched expression as an rvalue?
The code:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func(int& param)
{
    cout << param << endl;
}

int main()
{
    long long param;
    func(param);
    return 0;
}

The compiler error is:
10:10: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘int&’ to an rvalue of type ‘int’
10 |     func(param);
   |          ^~~~~
 3 | void func(int& param)
   |           ~~~~~^~~~~


For the same reason int a; double &m = a; fails. See Non const lvalue references cannot be bound to an lvalue of different type and good c++ book. Basically, this is not allowed by the standard.

An int is not a long long, and a long long is not an int. The purpose of an int & is to refer to an int, not to a long long (and, conversely, the purpose of a long long & is to refer to a long long, not to an int). If (hypothetically) creating an int & that refers to a long long was allowed, then all subsequent usage of that reference would give undefined behaviour - and preventing the conversion prevents that.

The function expects a reference to an int variable, but you pass it a long long instead, so the compiler creates a temporary int to assign the long long value to. That temporary is an rvalue, and a non-const reference cannot bind to an rvalue, hence the error.
Add const to the parameter and then the code will work. A const reference can bind to an rvalue.
void func(const int& param)
{
    cout << param << endl;
}

Or, get rid of the reference and just pass the int by value.
void func(int param)
{
    cout << param << endl;
}

